# Ruby on Rails Map API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, maps

I'm looking to include a map widget in a RoR 3 app I'm building that allows users to drop markers and name them.  The locations (latitude and longitude) and names associated with these markers need to be saved to a database.

Are there any gems or APIs (I checked out Google Maps and MapBox a little) that you can recommend for this?  Also any help on how to set this up in RoR would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby-toolbox is a good resource for finding gems

Some additional gems [here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/geocoding___maps)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails. If you need Geocoding then http://www.rubygeocoder.com/.